# Error when using Beautiful Soup in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

My code works fine. However with certain data my code gives error. the problematic data is:
T turns 10 this month. In honor of the anniversary and the upcoming T@10 Issue, this series looks back at some of the most memorable stories from the magazines first decade.

the reported problem is

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/mas/Documents/workspace/DeepLearning/BagOfWords.py", line 41,
>   in 
>       clean_train_reviews.append(" ".join(KaggleWord2VecUtility.review_to_wordlist(train["Snippet"][i],
>   True)))   File
>   "/Users/mas/Documents/workspace/DeepLearning/KaggleWord2VecUtility.py",
>   line 22, in review_to_wordlist
>       review_text = BeautifulSoup(review).get_text()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/**init**.py", line 162, in
>   **init**
>       elif len(markup) <= 256: TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

the code :

```
def deprecated_argument(old_name, new_name):
        if old_name in kwargs:
            warnings.warn(
                'The "%s" argument to the BeautifulSoup constructor '
                'has been renamed to "%s."' % (old_name, new_name))
            value = kwargs[old_name]
            del kwargs[old_name]
            return value
        return None

    parse_only = parse_only or deprecated_argument(
        "parseOnlyThese", "parse_only")

    from_encoding = from_encoding or deprecated_argument(
        "fromEncoding", "from_encoding")

    if len(kwargs) > 0:
        arg = kwargs.keys().pop()
        raise TypeError(
            "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % arg)

    if builder is None:
        if isinstance(features, basestring):
            features = [features]
        if features is None or len(features) == 0:
            features = self.DEFAULT_BUILDER_FEATURES
        builder_class = builder_registry.lookup(*features)
        if builder_class is None:
            raise FeatureNotFound(
                "Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you "
                "requested: %s. Do you need to install a parser library?"
                % ",".join(features))
        builder = builder_class()
    self.builder = builder
    self.is_xml = builder.is_xml
    self.builder.soup = self

    self.parse_only = parse_only

    if hasattr(markup, 'read'):        # It's a file-type object.
        markup = markup.read()
    elif len(markup) <= 256:
        # Print out warnings for a couple beginner problems
        # involving passing non-markup to Beautiful Soup.
        # Beautiful Soup will still parse the input as markup,
        # just in case that's what the user really wants.
        if (isinstance(markup, unicode)
            and not os.path.supports_unicode_filenames):
            possible_filename = markup.encode("utf8")
        else:
            possible_filename = markup
        is_file = False
        try:
            is_file = os.path.exists(possible_filename)
        except Exception, e:
            # This is almost certainly a problem involving
            # characters not valid in filenames on this
            # system. Just let it go.
            pass
        if is_file:
            warnings.warn(
                '"%s" looks like a filename, not markup. You should probably open this file and pass the filehandle into Beautiful Soup.' % markup)
        if markup[:5] == "http:" or markup[:6] == "https:":
            # TODO: This is ugly but I couldn't get it to work in
            # Python 3 otherwise.
            if ((isinstance(markup, bytes) and not b' ' in markup)
                or (isinstance(markup, unicode) and not u' ' in markup)):
                warnings.warn(
                    '"%s" looks like a URL. Beautiful Soup is not an HTTP client. You should probably use an HTTP client to get the document behind the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup.' % markup)

    for (self.markup, self.original_encoding, self.declared_html_encoding,
     self.contains_replacement_characters) in (
        self.builder.prepare_markup(markup, from_encoding)):
        self.reset()
        try:
            self._feed()
            break
        except ParserRejectedMarkup:
            pass

    # Clear out the markup and remove the builder's circular
    # reference to this object.
    self.markup = None
    self.builder.soup = None
```

this is my main code:

```
import os
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from KaggleWord2VecUtility import KaggleWord2VecUtility
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data', 'NYTimesBlogTrain.csv'), header=0)
    test = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data', 'NYTimesBlogTest.csv'), header=0)

    print 'A sample Abstract is:'
    print train["Abstract"][2838]

    print 'A sample Snippet is:'
    print train["Snippet"][2838]
    #raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")


    #print 'Download text data sets. If you already have NLTK datasets downloaded, just close the Python download window...'
    #nltk.download()  # Download text data sets, including stop words

    # Initialize an empty list to hold the clean reviews
    clean_train_reviews = []

    # Loop over each review; create an index i that goes from 0 to the length
    # of the movie review list
    print len(train["Snippet"])
    print "Cleaning and parsing the training set abstracts...\n"
    for i in xrange( 0, 3000):
        clean_train_reviews.append(" ".join(KaggleWord2VecUtility.review_to_wordlist(train["Snippet"][i], True)))
        if not train["Snippet"][i]:
            print i  
#
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, this issue was caused by having some samples containing no data at all in the review feature. You can change this and set the samples with no reviews to be blank by using the following:

```
train = train.fillna(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the full context  (e.g the value of `review` that gets passed into constructor)  is it possible your KaggleWord2VecUtility method is splitting on the @ symbol and/or the digit, such that a token is being passed as a float instead of a string/unicode object? The exception indicates that `markup` is an unexpected float when init is expecting a string or unicode object

```
def __init__(self, markup="", features=None, builder=None,
             parse_only=None, from_encoding=None, **kwargs):
```

Comment: this is the value of my review: T turns 10 this month. In honor of the anniversary and the upcoming T@10 Issue, this series looks back at some of the most memorable stories from the magazines first decade. @randalv

Comment: What version of Beautiful Soup? get_text didn't resolve for me with 3.2.1 and I can't reproduce with bs4 (4.3.2) if I pass review as a string with that exact value.

Comment: I am using bs4 @randalv

Comment: More specifically? Can you repro if you create new file with only: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
review = "T turns 10 this month. In honor of the anniversary and the upcoming T@10 Issue, this series looks back at some of the most memorable stories from the magazines first decade."
review_text = BeautifulSoup(review).get_text()
print review_text
(Thought I could format code in comment, guess not - I could edit original post, but hopefully you can read this)

Comment: Assuming same python environment (and assuming that's the same way you're doing the module import), then something prior has to be modifying this value before it's getting passed into the constructor.